# Anyway to reverse a male USB device to a Micro port?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, bluetooth

So I have a wireless mouse but it's not bluetooth.  So I would like to see if it's possible to use it on my Galaxy Tab A.  It has the USB mini female port on the bottom.  Is there any way to do this?

Also, I have a USB splitter into four USB plugs, I am thinking if there is an adapter to go into the bottom of my Galaxy Tab, I could use this also.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. OK I will answer this vs. deleting it.  The answer is an OTG cable which is easy to find :)

[image]

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state. For example: https://i.imgur.com/2eRipOg.png and some detail regarding that, what it does to resolve, etc.